# Normal CPU compared to Turbo frequency?

Tags: cpu, performance

When I look at the Intel CPU's `i5-4570T` and `i3-4340`, the main [difference](http://ark.intel.com/compare/75045,77771) seams to be

```
Processor Number     i3-4340    i5-4570T
# of Cores                 2           2
# of Threads               4           4
Clock Speed          3.6 GHz     2.9 GHz
Max Turbo Frequency              3.6 GHz
Max TDP                 54 W        35 W
```

**Question**

Are the two CPU's equally fast or can normal CPU speed not be compared to Turbo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel's [Turbo Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost) feature allows the CPU to dynamically adjust the clock rate of each core to meet demand.  For example, a 2-core CPU can disable an idle core and overclock the other core.  There are other specs besides clock speed, such as cache size, which will also influence the performance.  The only way to know for certain whether one CPU will perform better than the other is to review benchmarks of each CPU running your target application(s).

Comment: Very interesting! What if it were a quad core with Turbo? How many cores would it then disable?

Comment: It's based on demand, so you could potentially have just 1 active core.  I've added a link to the Wikipedia Turbo Boost article, which has a nice example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost#Example

Answer (score 0):

On paper, they seem to be just as fast as each other.
Both have the same amount of cache as well.

The i5 has the benefit that it is a lower power model, and as such uses less power when idle, and at full turbo speed, it can match the i3. The i5 also has some power user features which you probably won't use though.

However, the i3 has the price advantage, and is always running at it's maximum speed but also uses more power.

For some more information - check these intel product pages
[i3-4340](http://ark.intel.com/products/77771)
[i5-4570T](http://ark.intel.com/products/75045)

Answer (score 0):

Well some processors do their work by efficiency and others by frequency. The have some architectural differences:

> http://ark.intel.com/compare/77771,75045

As for the benchmark results:
i3-4340:

> http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i5-4570T+%40+2.90GHz&id=2041

i5-4570T:

> http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i5-4570T+%40+2.90GHz&id=2041

It seems that the i3 is faster frequency-wise, but there are other some other technologies that might help with certain applications. I hope this helps.